# How can I setting admin session using admin guards the same as we use in user

Tags: php, laravel

Am have table of students where i need them to access the forms sent by admin and apply them,, am trying to use pivot table to access, but it seems that i need to have different tables to access forms from admin to students then retreive them back(by admin), but it tells me

> "Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::admin does not exist"

I tried to set multiple authentication and set the guards for admin, but it seems to require a session so that i can use `auth()->admin()->name` the same as `auth()->user()->name` I am totally frustrated now, if there is any possibility of setting these two sessions (user, and admin) please how does it done, thanks.

Below are my guards

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    // 'admins' => [
    //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
    //     'model' => App\Admin::class,
    // ],
     // 'defaults' => [
     //        'driver' => 'session',
     //        'provider' => 'admins',
     //    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

         'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

           'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

I expect to log in as admin and using the same as we use in user model
but i encoutered this error

> "ErrorException (E_ERROR) Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::admin
>   does not exist. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ftss\resources\views\inherit\admin.blade.php) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ftss\resources\views\inherit\admin.blade.php)"

Comment: do you have admin model?

Comment: @Makaveli instead of checking Admin why not you are checking just user is logged in or not?

Comment: And manage the conditions based on user role.

Comment: @Makaveli clarify me one thing... does each student has their own login?

Comment: Do follow this tutorial could help you to understand the concept.. https://hackernoon.com/laravel-multiple-authentication-80daa855322b

Comment: Just verify if the logged in user is `Admin` show him the admin routes... else consider the user as student.

Comment: The problem started when I wanted to capture student id to store in pivot table which has forms id, it required me to have the authenticated user so thus why I decided to keep them in their table so that I can get their ids' but it seems confusing when I try to use the admin guard to log in so that I can post forms (sorry for my bad English). @Vikash Phatak

Comment: @Makaveli how you identify the user is `Admin`?

Comment: I use 'if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)){ //redirection here }' @VikashPathak

Comment: And for the student login?

Comment: Thanks your time bro,,, @Vikash Pathak i tried to use 'auth then endauth in blades ' it seems to work fine, but whenever i click the other page from the dashboard the admin is not recognized anymore (i.e when i need to add post, the links from side bar and navbar all disappear) no errors but the layout i extended for admin does not show any thing concern to admin, and if student logged in it works fine the problem is on the admin guards,

Comment: I solved it.. the issue was in the controllers i have to use some middlewares

Comment: You are welcome! Awesome man.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by writing simple codes in blade
i check if is guest then if not i proceeded
'

```
@guest
@else
{{auth()->user()->name}}
@endguest
```

'